# Copying files to SD card through bash script corrupts data

Tags: bash

I generated a simple bash script to copy files to an SD card. I want to copy the boot image to the boot partition and binaries/libraries to the root partition. This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -d /media/user/boot ]
then
    if [ -d /media/user/root ]
    then
        cp -v output/boot/boot.bin /media/user/boot
        sudo cp -rvp output/devroot/* /media/user/root/
        echo "Sync"
        sync
        echo "Eject"
        sudo eject /dev/sdc
        echo "Ready to test"
    else
        echo "Mount root!"
    fi
else
    echo "Mounting boot!"
fi
```

When I plugged again my SD card I read messages like these when running dmesg:

> FAT-fs (sdc1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be
>   corrupt.
>
> Please run fsck. I/O error, dev sdc, sector 90514

And the partitions are not well mounted.

If I run manually the commands all goes ok.

Comment: Try to put a `sleep 5` (which will make the computer sleep for 5 seconds) after sync and eject and check if this will resolve the corruption issue. Another Idea would be to end the sync command with `&&` which will let the script only continue if the command was successful.

Comment: Thanks! I changed the SD card reader and now It seems to work properly. Although I will take into account your recommendations.

Comment: When you have finally solved this it would be nice if you asnwer your own question then with a comprehensive answer covering what went wrong and how your script turned out in the end :) so people find maybe an answer if they hit the same roadblock as you did.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was not related with the script. When I changed the card reader it started to work properly.

I took into consideration the comment from Videonauth: "Another Idea would be to end the sync command with && which will let the script only continue if the command was successful." Hence this is my final script which is going ta save several seconds of my life:

```
#!/bin/bash

BOOT=$1
ROOT=$2

if [ -d $BOOT ]
then
    if [ -d $ROOT ]
    then
        cp -v output/boot/boot.bin $BOOT
        sudo cp -rvp output/devroot/* $ROOT
        echo "Sync"
        sync &&
        echo "Eject"
        sudo eject /dev/sdc
        echo "Ready to test"
    else
        echo "Mount root!"
    fi
else
    echo "Mount boot!"
fi
```